# Which MYSQL Join to include not existing records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database that I want to query for all records in products joined with product_fields. But it is possible there is no record in product_fields for the color, in that case I still want to have a record shown, only field color can be left empty. The product_fields table consist of several records for the same product and has a 'name' and 'value' field.

See this statement I came up with:

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_fields c ON c.product_id = products.id 
WHERE c.name = 'color'
AND products.id = '1'
```

To my surprise this does not work, I must have left something obvious out? Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE c.name = 'color'` means if c.name doesn't exist, the WHERE condition will fail and you won't get the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the condition in the `ON` clause,

```
SELECT p.*, c.value AS color
FROM   products p
       LEFT JOIN product_fields c 
            ON c.product_id = products.id AND 
               c.name = 'color'
WHERE  products.id = '1' 
LIMIT  1
```

The main difference between adding a condition in the `ON` clause and on the `WHERE` clause is that, in `ON` clause, it filters out the records from the specified table before joining it on the other table while `WHERE` clause filters out records after the table has been joined.

Comment: See something obvious.. It works now, thanks for the quick response and provided background info!  Will accept when possible.

Comment: `WHERE` does filter after the join, but since this a left join, all the records are still present when evaluating the `WHERE` clause. The reason records with no value in `product_fields` are included is because `c.name` will be `NULL`, not `color`. Alternatively, you could change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE (c.name = 'color' OR c.name IS NULL) AND products.id = '1'`.

Comment: That said, modifying the join condition as @JW did is certainly cleaner than changing the `WHERE` clause.